# CN1 Graphics.drawImage with aliasing effects after rotation

Tags: draw, codenameone

How can I draw an `Image` anti-aliased? My current code looks like this:

```
    boolean wasAAed = g.isAntiAliased();
    g.setAntiAliased(true);

    g.rotate(rotRad, originX, originY);
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);

    g.setAntiAliased(wasAAed);
```

but produces aliasing effects when rotating the image to be drawn...

[image: default drawn image]
[image: rotated drawn image]

just for comparison with libgdx's drawing (as illustration based on my comment to the accepted answer):

[image: libgdx drawing with linear texture filtering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-aliasing won't work for an image. You will see artifacts in rotation of an image as conceptually on device it's impractical to do an efficient rotation with the details. This isn't anti-aliasing as much as a rotation algorithm.

The image you are rotating is really simple and you can probably use the code from the clock demo to produce such an image with vector commands which would rotate smoothly when anti-aliasing is enabled.

Comment: hmm isn't there any possiblity to do such rotations? Do I have to implement it via native interfaces or maybe web view? Yeah the image is simple, but I just used it for testing purposes. I would like to rotate more complex images.

Comment: Native can't do that either since it's a conceptual problem. Images are just pixels and when you rotate them the math to do that smoothly is pretty complex. Hardware rotation algorithms aren't as clever and use a relatively simple rotation algorithm. Even on a powerful desktop in photoshop try rotating an image you will notice pixelation while dragging and only when you accept the change you will notice that photoshop takes a second until the pixelation goes away.

Comment: ok I see.. as a libgdx guy I'm missing anti-aliasing in this case of cn1 (I know, game dev frameworks need to have another handling of texture drawing.. I'm not trying to make cn1 look bad :) since it's rather for none-gaming applications). I guess I need to think about a workaround.

Comment: We use roughly the same logic they do (Open GL) so they should have the same level of artifacts for an image of this type

Comment: with linear texture filtering in libgdx the drawing looks appropriate despite rotation (see the snapshot added to my question post)

Comment: I communicated that with Steve and he says it's possible that we can improve this but it would require some pipeline work which we don't have the time to do right now. On some of the ports this works better than others so this will require going to every port and tuning it. Please file an RFE to tune this and I'll try to assign it into a 3.8 timeline

Comment: nice, looking forward to this. RFE created.